# Blur effect throught glass

Tags: blur, glass

What I'm trying to do in Blender is a blur effect in a way that, whenever something is not behind the crystal of the glasses, it should be blurred. That means, the sentence "Saw you there" should be clearly defined meanwhile "And I thought" should be blurred. Any ideas?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I need to clarify that it is an animation: "Saw you there" comes from the bottom of the scene and stays behind the crystal. The same with "And I though" but it comes from the top of the scene

Comment: This does not answer your question really but could you render out a "everything blurry" render and another "everything clear" and composite the two videos with a mask of some sort? I am sure this could be done in Blender without compositing but you will have to wait till someone who knows the math nodes better than me to help there.

Comment: Sounds like the work for postprocessing in the compositor

Comment: I know a way to achieve what you want through object masks and the compositor, but I'll have to post my solution later on in the day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the lenses object pass index to a value of 1 [image: Lens]

Then under the **layers panel** use the **passes** dropdown and enable **Object Index**

[image: Object Index]

Render that out and then head over to the compositor. Create a node setup as illustrated by the image below: [image: Compositor]

As you can see by this render, I believe it resolves your problem. [image: Final]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

**Put a refraction shader on a plane everywhere  *exept* the glasses' lenses.**

[image]

[image]